# Javascript Regex look till optional comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the Version from the longs string on the top line

https://regex101.com/r/9jsOai/1

There is an erroneous comma that sometimes appears in the output. I nned to grab Group 1 "03.06.07b.E" and if the comma is present up to excluding the comma.

Complete string:

Name/OID: model.0; Value (OctetString): Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software, Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version **03.06.07b.E**, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2017 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 30-Oc

Comment: Can you provide a test case where the comma is part of the match?

Comment: Like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/9jsOai/2)

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the question

Comment: Edit with complete string added. Bolded part is desired extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.

```js
var regex = new RegExp("Version ([^,]*)(,)? RELEASE");

var value1 = `Name/OID: model.0; Value (OctetString): Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software, Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 03.06.07b.E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2017 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 30-Oc`;
var value2 = `Name/OID: model.0; Value (OctetString): Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software, Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 03.06.07b.E, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2017 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 30-Oc`;

var match = regex.exec(value1);
console.log(match[1]);
var match = regex.exec(value2);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try it `Version (.*)(,)? RELEASE`

https://regex101.com/r/9jsOai/4

Comment: Version (.*)(,)? RELEASE contains the comma in group 1 when present.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should work: `/Version ([^,]*),? RELEASE/g`. In your original regex you are capturing *any character* any number of times as the version number. What you want to match is any character **except a comma** any number of times up till the separating comma, that is, `([^,]*)`. The question mark after the comma makes the comma optional. Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/9jsOai/6).

Comment: /Version ([^,]*), RELEASE/g - this only matches when  comma is present